# How to browse a Windows Phone 8 device on OS X?

Tags: 8.0, macos

On Windows you can plug in and browse (and modify) your Windows Phone 8 device using the file explorer. OS X doesn't support the MTP protocol so you cannot browse it using Finder. I have tried both the Windows Phone for Mac and the Android file transfer applications and neither work.

How can I copy files directly to my device on OS X?

Answer (score 5):

On OS X, unfortunately, you cannot transfer any files other than photos and videos (using the Windows Phone app).

However, you can change the extensions of the files you want to copy to .mp3/4 and then transfer them to your phone. Once copied, you should see your files sitting pretty in the Music/Videos folder in your Windows Phone. You can then rename them back to their original extensions from the Files app.

A neat little trick, but shouldn't be necessary, really.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with Mac based hardware, but I do know there is a [Windows Phone](https://itunes.apple.com/US/app/windows-phone-7-connector/id415571499) app that might be able to help you. Have a go, and see what it does or does not do on Macs exactly.

Comment: As mentioned in the post I have tried the official app.

Answer (score 1):

I was directed here, but like many others I just wanted to get a photo (or word document) off of the phone.  These files may already be on your Live/OneDrive account, which is also used to store content.

So when I want to get data from my phone to a random MAC (like the one at work or a friends MAC), I use the cloud as follows:

1) Use Safari to log into your live account and check OneDrive.  My documents and photos are saved there automatically.  Files can be managed online.

2) If there not, use the phone to "share" the photos/files to OneDrive (or elsewhere)

Both the Windows phone and iPods/iPads hide the file interface from the user and expect you to manage the content "in the cloud"
When I started using the windows phone, I was upset that all my contacts and photos were "in the cloud".   Then I dropped and broke my phone and all my photos and documents were restored on the new one automatically.

Syncing data to "The Cloud" and managing data "In The Cloud" is probably the correct paradigm for the average user (exception to developers, who know everything is really a file)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [official windows app](https://itunes.apple.com/US/app/windows-phone-7-connector/id415571499) by microsoft. I am using this app. it works almost like itunes sync. if you don't have any problem with itunes, it should also work like a charm.

Comment: As mentioned in the post I have tried the official app.

Comment: there is no other way to transfer files directly to windows phone, it is a closed system like iOS, and doesn't allow direct file transfer.

Comment: As mentioned in the post, Windows Phone 8 supports MTP, so it does allow drag-and-drop for certain file types on Windows.